# Clear beanstalk queue (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-artisan, beanstalkd

Project on larvel in Kubernetes
I need clear queue
My process

```
/var/www $ ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 www-data  0:41 {supervisord} /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf -n
  346 www-data  0:00 /bin/sh
  393 www-data  0:53 php artisan queue:work --queue=messenger.hook.accept.0
  394 www-data  0:01 php artisan queue:work --queue=bot.run.accept.0
```

When i make

```
php artisan queue:clear
```

i get

```
Clearing queues is not supported on [BeanstalkdQueue]
```

How clear queue? (some queue or all)